# Disable swagger try-it-out for certain endpoints (regardless of submit methods)

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am trying to disable the `try it out` feature of the Swagger UI for **certain** endpoints only. These are regardless of their http method. I know it is possible to disable either for all endpoints by adding to the Startup configuration:

```
c.SupportedSubmitMethods(new SubmitMethod[] {});
```

As part of the `UseSwaggerUI` options. I also aware of disabling the `try it out` feature for specific http method endpoints, such as only display the `Get` methods using:

```
c.SupportedSubmitMethods(new SubmitMethod[] { SubmitMethod.Get });
```

However, I need to disable `try it out` for a selection of endpoints, that are not common for one http method only. The use case is that I am currently in the transition of updating endpoint authentication from API-keys to an OAuth2.0 clients credentials flow. Newly added endpoints are thus, not secured with API-keys - as we would like our customers to be able to integrate towards the new endpoints straight away, and then configure the OAuth flow once this is added. So I have some endpoints, that are configured with API-keys (running over Azure APIM) which cannot be called directly without throwing a `403` code. So to avoid any confusing, until the OAuth authentication is added, I would like to disable the `try it out` for the older endpoints, while the new ones should have it.

Ideally it would be nice to have a simple decorator, or attribute that could be added to those endpoints that I do want to hide (eg. something like `[SubmitMethod(false)]` - however this is just a plain pseudo sample to prove my point here).

As a side note, I am developing using .NetCore 3.1.

Comment: Neither Swagger UI nor Swashbuckle support this out-of-the-box, but it could be done by writing a custom [plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/customization/plugin-api.md) for Swagger UI. The plugin will need to override the `allowTryItOutFor` selector to return `false` for operations that need "try it out" disabled. You'll also need to [provide a custom index.html](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#customize-indexhtml) to be used by Swashbuckle.

Comment: Another possible solution might be to [split](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#generate-multiple-swagger-documents) new endpoints into a separate API doc and configure it with empty `SupportedSubmitMethods` list.