# Disable springfox swagger UI Try it out button for specific end point in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I want to disable the *Try it out* button of spring fox swagger UI for only one specific endpoint. I am aware that we can disable the *try it out* button by giving an empty array in supportedSubmitMethods() of UI Configuration however I want to disable *Try it out* only for a specific endpoint.

I am using  `<springfox-swagger2.version>2.9.2</springfox-swagger2.version>`.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67811873/disable-swagger-try-it-out-for-certain-endpoints-regardless-of-submit-methods

Comment: yes @humbleCoder almost. but any useful references in spring boot is highly appreciated.